# Extracting Date from a String

Tags: reporting-services, substring, reportbuilder3.0

I have a string such as "5/12/2014 1:14:50 PM" and I am trying to extract the date (5/12/2014) from that string. I tried using (Created.Value contains the string):

```
SUBSTRING(Fields!Created.Value, 1,9)
```

But it gave me an error saying "The Value expression for the textrun 'Created>Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30451]Name 'substring' is not declared."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `SubString` expression in SSRS - you will need to use `Mid`:

```
=Mid(Fields!Created.Value, 1, 9)
```

Assuming all your inputs are well formed you could always convert the string to a date:

```
=CDate(Fields!Created.Value)
```

Then adjust the **Format** property to the Textbox.